# Automatically log in to wireless hotspot

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I have a MacBook Pro that I keep at work by my Office PC.  From time to time, I want to be able to connect to my laptop from home.  The only problem with this is when you connect to my office network, it makes you authenticate every 6 hours or so.  Similar to when you go to StarBucks to connect to their free wireless.  There is a webpage that opens up which you have to enter a username and password in order to let you access the internet.

I am running OSX Mountain Lion on my laptop.  I am looking for an app or a way to automatically log into the website when ever it is needed so I can always access my laptop from at home if needed.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the sound of it, the requirement that you reauthenticate every 6 hours is something your employer decided was a good idea, even if you find it annoying.  Is it a similarly good idea to risk your job by trying to circumvent their policy?

Comment: Thanks, Nicole.  This answered my question perfectly.  Kudos to you.

Comment: LOL.  Oddly, I just got downvoted by someone.  Good luck.  (Fwiw, I do understand your frustration.  Working for a living, you get an income, but the rest of the arrangement's not quite as appealing.)

Comment: Keep up the amazing work!

Comment: Hey, this isn't workplace SE, is it?